# What game is this scene with Tupolev Tu-95 like aircraft from?

Tags: game-identification

[image]

I wonder what game is this? It looks pretty cool, the closest I can come to is Red Alert but they have advanced technology and not Tupolev Tu-95 like aircrafts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This game is [World in Conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_in_Conflict), an RTS about a modern conflict between the US and Russia. Your image is shown in the Wikipedia article. It focuses on unit based combat, with additional fire support available as special abilities. Instead of base building, you select a drop zone on the map, and use reinforcement points to call in reinforcements. Gameplay involves completing objectives (usually capturing points or eliminating the enemy) with the limited resources you have available.

Your image shows aircraft carpet-bombing an area of land, which is one of the fire support options you can use in the game.

Comment: I know WiC, but really Tupolev bombers in that game? I need to pay more attention. I had some hopes for another game thought. Thanks :)

Comment: There was an expansion for it: Soviet Assault, which added playing as the Russian army, including the occasional Tupolev ;-).